# Issue on installing a build agent for TFS 2017

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines

I have a stand-alone single server TFS 2017 RTM installation on SQL Express. It is not in any domain, but on my laptop. Have brought it up for my own usage (for learning too). Set it up to run on a self-signed certificate for SSL.

Thought of setting up a vNext build agent on the same machine. I remember somewhere in my brain that build machine should be not in the TFS app tier, to reduce surface attack. Well I don't really bother now about surface attacks. But rather I need a working TFS with build setup as well.

While configuring after entering the URL (https URL), I get prompted for authentication type. I typed Negotiate. After entering credentials, I get below error.

```
TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required.
```

Upon using Integrated for the authentication type, I get below error.

```
An error occurred while sending the request.
Failed to connect.  Try again or ctrl-c to quit
```

When I use the http site for URL I get below error for both the authentication types.

```
Connecting to server ...
Found
Failed to connect.  Try again or ctrl-c to quit
```

I am able to ping to my URL.

Below is the error log from _diag folder.

```
[2016-11-23 19:53:40Z INFO CredentialManager] Creating type Integrated
[2016-11-23 19:53:40Z INFO CredentialManager] Creating credential type: Integrated
[2016-11-23 19:53:40Z INFO IntegratedCredential] GetVssCredentials
[2016-11-23 19:53:40Z INFO ConfigurationManager] cred retrieved
[2016-11-23 19:53:40Z INFO Terminal] WRITE LINE: Connecting to server ...
[2016-11-23 19:53:41Z INFO CommandSettings] Flag 'unattended': 'False'
[2016-11-23 19:53:41Z ERR  Terminal] WRITE ERROR (exception):
[2016-11-23 19:53:41Z ERR  Terminal] Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssServiceResponseException: Found
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.HandleResponse(HttpResponseMessage response)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__45.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__42`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Location.Client.LocationHttpClient.<GetConnectionDataAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.<ConnectAsync>d__41.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.AgentServer.<ConnectAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Listener.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.<TestConnectAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Listener.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.<ConfigureAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Could you access TFS from web access?

Comment: Yes - I can access it from web access.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable anonymous authentication and enable windows authentication for your TFS.

Since you set up TFS for your own usage, you can consider using [Visual Studio Team Service](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/) instead of on-premise TFS. VSTS is free for 5 users.

Comment: yes I have VSTS as well. Trying to make it work with an on-prem installation too.

I don't see Windows authentication in the Authentication, I might need to get it unlocked in IIS.

Will try the option and let you know.

Comment: Let us know your test result.

Comment: Sure. It is on my laptop. So will do it within a couple of days and let you know.

Comment: My Win 10 edition is "Windows 10 Home Single Language" and as per this [page](http://superuser.com/questions/482428/missing-windows-authentication-feature) I need to have either Pro or Enterprise edition.

Without Windows Authentication I cannot go any further with the build setup?

I could setup a build for VSTS though from the same machine!

Comment: How about using NTLM?

Comment: Could you explain please where do you want me to use NTLM?

1. In the authentication for IIS site? Or
2. During the build agent configuration?

Comment: I mean when you configure TFS and configure build agent.

Comment: NTLM is used while configuring TFS. Even in TFS Admin console it displays as NTLM.

While configuring Build agent for authentication the default is Integrated. I have tried Negotiate as well. It did not work. I have mentioned this in the question itself.

I am planning to see if by any chance the unattended option might work. Basically planning to see with the below command. `\config.cmd --unattended --url http://mylocaltfsserver:8080/tfs --auth Negotiate --username DOMAIN\USER_NAME --password MyPassword --pool
 default --agent myagent`

Answer (score 0):

Try using PAT for the authentication type, and get the personal access token, from the Security page in your profile menu. Using Selected scope -  Agent Pools (read, manage)

See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=825113

The personal access token is used to register the agent. One final step is suppying the credentials for the Agent Service.

Comment: I tried this and I am getting below error.. System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: The parameter is incorrect
   at System.Net.Http.WinHttpAuthHelper.SetWinHttpCredential(SafeWinHttpHandle requestHandle, ICredentials credentials, Uri uri, UInt32 authScheme, UInt32 authTarget)
   at System.Net.Http.WinHttpAuthHelper.CheckResponseForAuthentication(WinHttpRequestState state, UInt32& proxyAuthScheme, UInt32& serverAuthScheme)
   at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.<StartRequest>d__101.MoveNext()

Comment: At what step in configuring the agent do you get this error? Seems like an authentication problem in general with TFS.

Comment: I could open tfs in web.. while configuring after I provide tfs URL I get the error..

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that could have gone wrong.

After following Remko's answer and proceeding with "PAT" switch to "Negotiate" method, if you still cant get it working due to "An error occurred while sending the request", it is probably due to certificate issue. In such case, you can simply skip the certificate validation step which happens internally with curl by passing the parameter -sslskipcertvalidaion like below.

```
./config.sh --sslskipcertvalidation
```

Here's reference documentation :  [running agent with self-signed certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/certificate?view=azure-devops-2019)